# How to refresh auth token with the server

Tags: java, android, apache

I'm implementing a client-server system. The client logs in with username and password and (initially) the server responds with a token that expires in some hours and is used in the rest of services where the authentication is required.

When the token expires, how should I refresh it?

- Saving the username/password persistently (ciphered) and calling the login again
- Saving some kind of hash of the password?
- Any other option?

How should I send the password to the server?

- The client apply a hash and the server just stores it and validates hash (and never know the real password)
- The client send the raw password through a secure channel and the server validates (lenght,strength,etc) and store a hash?
- Any other option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this link. -> https://developers.hubspot.com/docs/methods/auth/refresh_token

From what I understand, when you first login with the password/username you should get a refresh token back which you save (to be used on refresh), along with the access token. Every so often you make a call to refresh your token to the server, you provide it with the refresh token and your access token and it gives you a new access token and refresh token.

I think the idea is that if someone sees one of your requests they can only impersonate you for a short while. They don't know the refresh token so assuming they don't see your request to refresh that token they would be cut off when you refresh and get a new access token.

I think sending the password through a secure channel would be fine.

Anyone else feel free to correct me here - I'm just trying to help out.